# Frequency Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency

I have seen this circuit on internet. I would like to understand what its purpose is.

It seems to be related to something which is call "jitter." I have done some research about "jitter" and I think that I have understood what it is. However I do not understand the circuit below and particulary how it works with its double feedbacks (positive and negative.)

[image]

Comment: Where did you find it?  Jitter doesn't occur by itself.

Comment: Looks to me like some kind of filter.

Comment: Have you tried running a simulation?

Comment: A badly transcribed relaxation oscillator. As it stands it wouldn’t work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get this Relaxation Oscillator or any for that matter, is to have both inputs Vin+- to have the same swing and average voltage for a 50% square wave.

This means if the output swing is. 2 to 13V for BJT type OA or 0 to 15 V for a CMOS  then the Vref. Input must be Vcc/2 and not 15V as shown. Then you get 50% duty cycle. Any change in this offset changes the duty cycle.

The Voltage divider Vout to Vin+ thus determines the swing  from this average voltage.  What is shown is 3.3/(3.3+1) or about 3/4 full swing exponential triangle.   Now the CMOS Schmitt Inverter OSC uses a hysteresis of 2/3 full square swing for the triangle..

Then with +/- 1/3  swing same as the 2/3 hysteresis,  the ramp is fairly linear but instead of 64% it is 66% but depends on tolerances with slight exponential response T=RC for f~ 1/2T.  Reducing the hysteresis increases the frequency just like changing the RC value.

[SIMULATION](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000015625%204.43302224444953%2061%2010%2050%0Aa%20304%20368%20432%20368%208%2015%200%201000000%205.065424841994029%2010.000164486339003%20100000%0Aw%20304%20352%20304%20304%202%0Ar%20304%20304%20432%20304%200%2010000%0Aw%20432%20304%20432%20368%200%0Aw%20432%20368%20432%20432%200%0Ar%20432%20432%20304%20432%200%20200000%0Aw%20304%20384%20304%20432%202%0Ar%20304%20432%20208%20432%200%20100000%0Ac%20304%20304%20208%20304%200%205.000000000000001e-7%205.065424841994029%0Ag%20208%20304%20208%20336%200%0A211%20432%20368%20512%20368%200%201%208000%201%0AR%20208%20432%20176%20416%200%200%2040%207.5%200%200%200.5%0Ao%208%208%200%2037123%2020%200.0015625%200%202%208%203%0Ao%2010%2016%200%204106%2020%200.00009765625%201%201%0A)